# Cannot load www.kernel.org in Chromium browser

Tags: chrome, browser

I have noticed recently that I can no longer access the website [www.kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) in Chromium. All I get is:

> This webpage is not available

However, I can access the website from Firefox.

My Chromium version is **37** on Debian Wheezy. I did not change anything in my setup, and I am sure it worked earlier, couple of months ago.

Other than [www.kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/), I am not aware of any other website that does not work. How could I troubleshoot this problem, to find out why this does not work?

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer: You should update your browser.

The recent version of Chromium is >= 54, and Google Chrome is also at >= 54. Chromium 37 is several years old, and many things have changed through all these years.

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561358/chromium-browser-is-stuck-at-version-37-0-2062-120-on-ubuntu-12-04-using-precis), we see that there were no updates for Chromium 37 in Ubuntu, and many people stuck in version 37.

> The OP is correct, there is no Chromium update to 37 for Precise. This
>   is a known bug and has been reported to launchpad bugs. The stable
>   repository has not been maintained for a few years and adding the
>   "stage" repository will result in upgrading to 48 which won't work on
>   12.04. As of now this is a problem as 37 is not compatible with the latest libnss3 update and any machine with chromium 37 & libnss3
>   update can't access google sites or content.

It seems that the same is true for Debian. Please upgrade your browser from the [Chromium website](https://www.chromium.org/developers/version-numbers), or download Google Chrome instead. It should fix the problem. But note that Google Chrome voilates many of Debian free software guidelines.

Comment: there is no way to upgrade chromium in Wheezy. I believe, this is due to incompatibility (gcc) of newer chromium versions. And for reasons beyond this discussion, I need to stay in Wheezy. Besides, yours is not really a useful answer. You cannot give knee-jerk answers to blindly upgrade, whenever a newer version is available.